# Adding PDF as page to PDF

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I'm working on an online bookstore. Obviously when something is bought we send out an invoice. I have a default template that is used to put all the information in (customer data) and of course the information about the bought items.

Now comes a part that might seem confusing. We are going to give discounts as well.

Example: A product is €100 and you get 10% discount. Now you pay just €90 but that missing €10 has to be paid at some point, by the one giving the discounts.

So once a month we send an additional invoice to the companies that gave discounts, with all the discounts they gave, so they know what to pay us.

On the first page of that invoice will be an overview for all orders with the total amount of discount on that order together with taxes and the order number. On the second page there will be a detailed overview of all orders.

I will show what is bought on the order so they can see where the discount came from and the prices are correct.

Now we finally get to the problem. The first page will hold (once again) all the details of the customer, in this case the company. It has the address, name, customer number, invoice number etc. The second page doesn't need this information, so I want to make a new template for that, giving me two template PDFs.

Is it possible to grab the second PDF and insert it into the PDF as a single page? This is all to be done in vb.net.

Comment: so you want insert a multipage pdf as single page in another pdf file?

Comment: no, not exactly.
I want to add a single page pdf as a page into another pdf file

Comment: So merging two PDFs? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7161747/231316

Comment: If it is your firm that is generating both PDFs, it would be much better to render a single PDF using the systems that you use to create them originally.

Comment: I would want a solution to a similar problem to yours. I wanted to insert pdf page 3 with some custom drawings to the 20 page pdf source document. Would want some solution for this.